# Permission denied (403) using Cloud Run Job execute's --update-env-vars (override) argument

Tags: google-cloud-run

When logged in as the project owner (full rights) and using the latest gcloud cli (v432.0.0), I am unable to *execute* a Cloud Run job (403 permission error) using the `--update-env-vars` argument. I can execute the same job without the argument. The project owner has *iam.serviceAccountUser* role on the job's service account.

Steps to reproduce my error:

```bash
# create a service account for job
gcloud iam service-accounts create sa-cloud-run-job
SERVICE_ACCOUNT=$(gcloud iam service-accounts list --filter='email:sa-cloud-run-job@*' --format='value(email)')

# grant current user the iam.serviceAccountUser role on job's service account 
USER_ACCOUNT=$(gcloud config get-value account)
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding ${SERVICE_ACCOUNT} --member="user:${USER_ACCOUNT}" --role='roles/iam.serviceAccountUser'

# create the hello-world cloud run job
gcloud alpha run jobs create hello-world-job --image hello-world --service-account=${SERVICE_ACCOUNT} --region us-central1

# execute job without --update-env-vars (WORKS)
gcloud alpha run jobs execute hello-world-job --region=us-central1 

# execute job with --update-env-vars (JOB DOES NOT RUN - 403 error)
gcloud alpha run jobs execute hello-world-job --region=us-central1 --update-env-vars=FOO=BAR
```

Error Output:

```
X Creating execution...                                                                                                                                                       
  . Provisioning resources...                                                                                                                                                 
Executing job failed                                                                                                                                                          
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.run.jobs.execute) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

For clarification, the *hello-world* image is not dependent on environment values. It was just used to demonstrate that the simplest image will not execute with the *--update-env-vars* argument.

Argument appears to be an alpha feature and documentation is currently lacking. I tried granting both the project owner and service account various roles (e.g. *roles/run.developer*) and I still encountered the same error. I granted the roles both at the project and resource binding level. Not sure which permissions are required.

Comment: Can you use `deploy` to set the envs followed by `execute` using the non-alpha commands? I think you have hit an `alpha` stage bug.

Comment: Without the alpha argument, I am able to deploy with envs and execute. I suspect a bug as well especially given I am logged in as the project owner.

Comment: Try giving `roles/run.jobs.admin` role to the serviceAccount with the following command `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding YOUR_PROJECT_ID --member=serviceAccount:sa-cloud-run-job@YOUR_PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/run.jobs.admin
` where replace YOUR_PROJECT_ID with your actual project ID. If this worked then there is no bug just a permissions issue.

Comment: Does my comment help ? If so acknowledge it, so I can post as an answer, If not then we can solve it further.

Comment: Did not work. Refer to your posted answer's comments for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private preview/alpha features in Cloud Run only work if your project has been specifically enabled for that alpha feature.

I suggest either using "update" followed by "execute", or waiting until the feature reaches Beta.

Comment: Thank you. TIL "alpha testing is to verify functionality and gather feedback from a limited set of customers". Unless your project is enabled to test the alpha feature(s), it will not work. Reference: https://support.google.com/a/answer/11202276

Answer (score 1):

As per your error it looks like your service account doesn't have the necessary roles to perform that activity, Although you have granted the `iam.serviceAccountUser` role to the service account, it might not have the necessary permissions to update the environment variables of the job.

- According to [documentations](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles#standard-roles) a cloud run service account should have a `run.jobs.admin` role to execute the cloud run job and yes that also includes updating the environmental variables.
- To give the `roles/run.jobs.admin` to the cloud run service account you can use following command :

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding YOUR_PROJECT_ID --member=serviceAccount:sa-cloud-run-job@YOUR_PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/run.jobs.admin
```

where replace `YOUR_PROJECT_ID` with your actual project ID.

Reference : [**IAM permissions required to create and execute**](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs#iam_permissions_required_to_create_and_execute)

Comment: Did not work. Plus your role `roles/run.jobs.admin` does not appear anywhere in your provided doc links or [GCP's role reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles). I have tried using `roles/run.admin` alternatively, which does not work either. The same error was encountered as originally posted.

Comment: I have early access to Cloud Run features. I receive an error for `roles/run.jobs.admin` as well. None of the IAM roles that I have access to have the permission `gcloud.alpha.run.jobs.execute`.

Comment: @John Hanley Apologies for the confusion there is already a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/282993667) registered about this issue in Buganizer.

Comment: I see that two tickets were opened, and both were closed. I guess we must wait for IAM to release the corresponding roles.

Comment: Both tickets were opened by me :) and both were immediately closed as *Won't fix (Infeasible)* by the Cloud Run team referring me here. I assume the team suspects that my issue is just a user-specific error with a lack of permissions.  For testing purposes, I even tried granting my job service account `roles/owner` role and still encounter same error. I noticed a (new?) `run.jobs.runWithOverrides` permission which may be related. With a lack of documentation on this feature, I was hoping the community can point out what I am missing or raise awareness to the team if it is truly a bug.